# Reading packets arriving at serial port

Tags: python, runtime-error

On my Arduino I'm receiving Zigbee I/O packets. Each packet has 26 bytes. I tried to execute the given program, and got an error.

This is the code:

```
import serial
ser=serial.Serial('COM17',9600,timeout=1)


while 1:

Data_in=ser.readline().encode('hex')
if Data_in[0:2]=='7e':
    Data_in.split('7e',-1)
    print("===================================")
    print("Found Packet :")
    print(Data_in)
    if Data_in[6:8]=='92':
        print("Packet type = Zigbee I/O Packet")
        AD=Data_in[22:24]
        print ("Device address")
        print(AD)
        SMH=Data_in[34:36]
        SML=Data_in[36:38]
        RH=Data_in[38:40]
        RL=Data_in[40:42]
        PH=Data_in[42:44]
        PL=Data_in[44:46]
        print("Soil moisture")
        print(SMH)
        print(SML)
        print("Rain")
        print(RH)
        print(RL)
        print("PIR")
        print(PH)
        print(PL)
    print("====================================")
print(" ")
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Windows\System32\chime2.py", line 5, in <module>
    Data_in=ser.readline().encode('hex')
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: Looks like you getting an bytes object from `readline`. If so, you do not need to encode into hex. The code looks like you have got strings from the readline method at some point. Did you copy the code from somewhere?

Comment: yup , i referred to code i found online n changed it according to my requirement :(

Comment: so does it mean i will get the packets in hexadeciml if i remove that encode('hex') part ??

Comment: I would use a debugger to inspect the result of `readline` or print the result to std out.

Answer (score 0):

The error is self explainatory: *AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'*.

You are using a Python 3.x interpretor and `serial.readline()` gives you a `bytes` object. In Python 3, strings are 16 bit unicode strings, and the `bytes` object does not support the `encode` method.

The correct way is to use `codecs.encode`, which will work the same in Python2 and Python3:

```
import codecs
...
Data_in=codecs.encode(ser.readline(), 'hex')
```

Alternatively, you could directly process the bytes, but it would require more changes in the remaining of the code.